# Generating the remaining values from a matrix using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

Suppose there is a matrix generated using `for` loop which is given as

```
A = [ 1 3 4 ;...
      5 8 9 ;...
      6 3 8 ]
```

Let another matrix be generated from a given `A` matrix as

```
B = [ 5 3 8 ]
```

My question is: I want to generate a matrix by removing only elements of `B` from `A` column wise only.

output

```
C = [ 1 8 4 ;... 
      6 3 9 ]
```

How to do this using Matlab?

Comment: matrix B is generated randomly. Only one element is removed from each column leading to generation of matrix C. What command could be used to generate matrix C

Comment: You have some inconsistency between rows and columns. `C` should be 3x2 according to your definition. Please edit your question accordingly and don't leave important information in comments.

Comment: @Ash :: In the second column, 3 comes two (row 1 and 3) times.... How do we know that the **3** in B is from row 1 and not 3 and vice-verca...the 2nd column in C can either be [8; 3] or [3; 8] ... Please clarify.....

Comment: @face :: B matrix is chosen from A randomly. Only 1 element from each column of A is picked. Therefore I am facing the same trouble in my program. The position can be determined but using setdiff command the order of values get changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work assuming that the number of elements removed from each row is the same.

```
A = [1 3 4; 5 8 9; 6 3 8];
B = [3 5 8];

C = A';
C(find(A' == repmat(B, size(A, 2), 1))) = [];
C = reshape(C, [], size(A, 1))'
```